# SQL-Server - Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Tags: sql-server

When I am executing this code I am having this error. ***Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int*** . What are the solutions to remove this error please? Thanks

```
CREATE FUNCTION [a01].[udf_isUserActive]
(@AccountID INTEGER)
    RETURNS BIT
    AS
    BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT  accountID
            FROM    [a01].[tbl_userAccounts]
            WHERE   accountID = @AccountID
                    AND isActive = 1))
    RETURN 1;

RETURN 0;
END;
GO
```

Comment: The datatype of `accountID` is presumably `uniqueidentifier` not integer.

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION [a01].[udf_isUserActive]
(@AccountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
    RETURNS BIT
    AS
    BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (SELECT  accountID
            FROM    [a01].[tbl_userAccounts]
            WHERE   accountID = @AccountID
                    AND isActive = 1))
    RETURN 1;

RETURN 0;
END;
GO

Comment: This is the good version ^ ?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably `tbl_userAccounts` has an `AccountID` of type `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and you are trying to compare @AccountID INTEGER with an `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

**Side note:** you should provide the entire context: table schema and function call context. It is a big change that calling the function may also lead to [performance problems](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381/T-SQL-Best-Practices-150-Don146t-Use-Scalar-Value-Functions-in-Column-List-or-WHERE-Clauses.htm) as scalar functions are called per each selected row.